# Expanding inner Veracrypt volume (FAT)

Tags: windows, veracrypt

Having a Veracrypt container with 6GB, I need to extend its size to 8GB. I used the volume expander of VC successfully. But it expands only the VC volume itself (= file size changed from 6 to 8GB) and not the inner filesystem (FAT in my case).

The VC volume isn't shown in the volume manager of Windows, neither on the CLI using `diskpart`. Those are the only ways for expanding volumes I know.

So how can I expand the inner FAT volume of my VC container using Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - apparently invisible to Windows in the normal way.

I copied the contents of the volume to another location (outside of the encrypted volume), and formatted the Veracrypt volume - you can format the entire (larger) space.  Then just copy everything back of course.